# "Years of experience" in careers should not be based solely on listed job history

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, tags, jobs, experience

I'm guessing that the years of experience in given tags is calculated based on the job history presented.  For a variety of reasons, I haven't listed all the jobs I've had over the last few decades, but this means the calculation is incomplete.

It is false to say, for instance, that I only have 3 or 5 years of [c](/questions/tagged/c) experience simply because I've only listed my most recent positions involving C.

Is there going to be an option to either put that number in by hand, or if we add all our job experience, but set some of the jobs not to be shown, that experience will add to that number as well, even though it's not being displayed to potential employers?

Comment: We're still discussing how exactly it should work, but we agree there's a problem here

Comment: on second thought, there are enough issues that we're going to yank the whole thing for active candidates until we can do it right

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow has [discontinued](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415293) Stack Overflow Jobs and Developer Story on March 31, 2022.

Answer (score 11):

I fully agree. In my CV, I now have “1 year experience in SQL” which looks kinda silly.

Anyway, I think Dan Dyer put it well in the [blog comments](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/careers-2-0-launches/#comment-57371):

> **The “x years experience” functionality
> isn’t going to be accurate enough to
> be useful.** It would be better to
> disable it (or at least give
> individual users the option to disable
> it).
>
> For example, if I want to list
> technology A for every position where
> I’ve used it I will have to leave
> other technologies out of my 10 tags.
> On the other hand, if I don’t list it
> for every position my experience will
> be understated.
>
> Also, if I list technology B for a
> position I held for 4 years, it will
> list 4 years experience, even if I
> only actually used it for 6 months.

So, either give us an **option to set the number of years manually**, or at least **allow disabling the feature** on a per-user basis. Pretty please.